# HTTP POST request, subdomain and SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, https, httprequest

A CAS server is trying to send a logout request via HTTP POST request to my webapp. But I'm not able to receive that request.

After few tests, it seems that the problem comes from a mix between the subdomain / the redirection and the SSL.

- If I send a POST request to https://mywebsite.com/theapp/ the app receives the request.
- But if I send a POST request to https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/theapp/ I never receive it. However, using Python or Curl, when setting the disabling the SSL verification, I receive the POST request on my subdomain.

It seems like a something has to be modified in the configuration file of Apache...but I don't know what.

Could someone help me ?

Thanking you in advance.

**EDIT :**

Those two part in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file might help to find the issue :

```
Redirect /subdomain https://subdomain.website.com
```

and

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain/
   ServerName subdomain.website.com
   SSLEngine ON
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.website.com/cert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.website.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: *"... in the configuration file of Nginx. ..."* - the certificate you have configured for the subdomain does not match the subdomain or is otherwise not valid. That's all what can be said based on these information. If this means you need to change the certificate since subdomain is not included or if you already have the correct certificate but did not configure it for the subdomain is impossible to say based on the information in the question.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I understand that with the information I gave it's pretty difficult to figure out the source of the issue. Unfortunately as I'm also shooting in the dark I really don't know what type of infos I could give.

Concerning the certificate solution : it's correct and up to date.

If there's any additionnal information that I can give I will. Meanwhile, if somebody else can imagine a possible cause for this problem, I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: *"it's correct and up to date"* - what makes you come to this conclusion? Did you check that the certificate actually explicitly covers the subdomain? Did you look at the certificate which you think is configured or did you look at the certificate which is actually configured for the subdomain? Are you even sure that your nginx is used when accessing the subdomain, i.e. does it resolve to the right IP address (check IPv4 and IPv6)?

Comment: What I did is that I connected to the website with my browser and checked the certificate (by clicking on the lock).

P.S.: I've edited my original post with more details. I hope it can help.

Comment: *"... connected to the website with my browser and checked the certificate ..."* - Did you connect to mywebsite.com or subdomain.mywebsite.com to check the certificate? Because just checking the first gives no information about the second - and the second is the problem you have according to your question.

Comment: I did indeed connect to the subdomain.website.com and then check for the certificate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230236/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-lucas1283).

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved, thanks to Steffen. Here's what I (we) did :

Using SSLLabs I've tested the SSL certificate. The result was an "Incomplete Certificate". Apparently browser can overcome this issue, but it wasn't the case of the CAS server (or Curl, or Python).

I had to complete the apache ssl.conf file with the SSLCertificateChainFile option.

That being done, I could send a secure POST request with curl and python. There were then still small changes to do for the logout function but the SSL certificate was the main issue. And now, finally, it all works.

Thank you very much for all your help Steffen (I never thought I could see the end of it, and your help was just tremendous) !